# PNP Search web part: search box and auto search (no enter)

Tags: pnp, pnp-search-webparts

Is it possible to start the search part when I type in some characters in the search box? At the moment it's necessary to press enter or select the arrow to start the search.

[image: Search with enter]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the PnP search web part cannot do this but you could make a suggestion via the [discussions](https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions) section on the GitHub repository.

Two other options are:

- Make the code changes to facilitate this functionality and make a pull request to the [PnP Modern Search repository](https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search).
- Fork the project and make the changes to the web part in your own repository.